# How to create multiple notification?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, notifications

This is my MyReceiver.java class and here i have written a code to display single notification. How to create multiple notification here.

```
         public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
String Reqpopending;
int MID=0;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dashboard)
            .setContentTitle("Dash Board Counts")
            .setContentText("P.O Counts-532,198,654,255,901 ZeroInward-303 PartialInward-777").setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());


    MID++;

}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Does every notification replaces or you want to make multiple notifications when `onReceive` is called ?

Comment: I want to show multiple notification on calling this class

Comment: I think you need to set different values for `MID` each time you generate new notification  so as to have multiple notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below the code which is being run in the loop

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
String Reqpopending;
int MID=0;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dashboard)
            .setContentTitle("Dash Board Counts")
            .setContentText("P.O Counts-532,198,654,255,901 ZeroInward-303 PartialInward-777").setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    notificationManager.notify((int)when, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Generate static count as `static int MID = 9999` and change the line to `notificationManager.notify(MID++, mNotifyBuilder.build());`, see if that works

Comment: Sorry there was an error in my code and i have cleared it. Now its working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NotificationId {
 private final static AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static int getID() {
        return c.incrementAndGet();
    }

 }
 notificationManager.notify(NotificationId .getID(), mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

AtomicInteger guarantees a unique integer every time your code is right, but there is minor bug somewhere, so it does work for multiple notification. This code is works for me, so you can try.

Comment: AtomicInteger  ganrate unic integer every time ur code is right but minor bug some where so it does work for multiple notification this code is porperly work for me so u can try

Comment: i have to show only 4 default notification.so what should i change in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

in this line of code

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

you have to give  different request codes like

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 3,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
 the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
 at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that
 is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents.
 This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
 `{@link Intent#filterEquals(Intent) Intent.filterEquals}`, or different
 request code integers supplied to `{@link #getActivity}`, `{@link #getActivities}`,
 `{@link #getBroadcast}`, or `{@link #getService}`.

Comment: What does that 0,1,2,3 refers ?

Comment: If I loop the  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     will it works?

Comment: you told me you have only four default notifications, by comparing message in notifcation you find which category the notification belongs and set the request code accordingly, ie inside a if or switch